# Varnish cookie issue with mantis bug tracker

Tags: linux, wordpress, cookies, varnish, mantis

I have installed Varnish on my Linux server and configured for my websites including a wordpress site (www.mywordpress.com) and it is working fine. Now I have installed mantis bug tracker under my website (www.mywordpress.com/mantis). But when I am trying to login to the MantisBT as the default user (administrator/root), it shows an error like "Your browser either does not know how to handle cookies, or refuses to handle them". How can I set up a Varnish exception or allow cookies (in default.vcl) for Mantis url's. My default.vcl file looks like:

---

```
###my default.vcl file:
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
backend master {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
acl purge {
    "localhost";
}
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
        error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
    return(lookup);
}
if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
        req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}


### do not cache these files:
if (req.url ~ "/svn" || req.http.Authorization || req.http.Authenticate)
{
    return (pass);
}

##never cache the admin pages, or the server-status page
if (req.url ~ "wp-(admin|login)" || req.http.Content-Type ~ "multipart/form-data")
{
    set req.backend = master;
    return(pass);
}

if (req.url ~ "opportunity-attachments" || req.http.Content-Type ~ "multipart/form-data")
{
    set req.backend = master;
    return(pass);
}

if (req.url ~ "^phpmyadmin") {
    set req.backend = master;
    return(pipe);
}

if (req.url ~ "^/login") {
    set req.backend = master;
    return(pipe);
}

## always cache these images & static assets
if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|ico|img|tga|wmf)$") {
    remove req.http.cookie;
    return(lookup);
}
if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "(xmlrpc.php|wlmanifest.xml)") {
    remove req.http.cookie;
    return(lookup);
}

#never cache POST requests
if (req.request == "POST")
{
    return(pass);
}
#DO cache this ajax request
if(req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest" && req.url ~ "recent_reviews")
{
    return (lookup);
}

#dont cache ajax requests
if(req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest" || req.url ~ "nocache" || req.url ~ "(control.php|wp-comments-post.php|wp-login.php|bb-login.php|bb-reset-password.php|register.php)")
{
    return (pass);
}

if (req.http.Cookie && req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_") {
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=", "; wpjunk=");
}
### don't cache authenticated sessions
if (req.http.Cookie && req.http.Cookie ~ "(wordpress_|PHPSESSID)") {
    return(pass);
}

### parse accept encoding rulesets to make it look nice
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
        # unkown algorithm
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}


if (req.http.Cookie)
{
    set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(vendor_region|PHPSESSID|themetype2)=", "; \1=");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

    if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
        remove req.http.Cookie;
    }
}

if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}
return(lookup);
}

sub vcl_hit {
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    set obj.ttl = 0s;
    error 200 "Purged.";
 }
}
sub vcl_miss {
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    error 404 "Not in cache.";
}
if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}

if (req.url ~ "^/[^?]+.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|js|css|txt|gz|zip|lzma|bz2|tgz|tbz|html|htm)(\?.|)$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.$", "");
}
if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}

}
sub vcl_fetch {
if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;

}

}
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change this, it is unsetting any cookie which not inside wp-login or wp-admin:

```
if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}
```

to something like this:

```
if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)") || !(req.url ~ "mantis")) {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}
```

(Where '||' means OR, '~' means equals to about, and 'req.url' - the requested URL)

and in vcl_recv (no matter where, put it in the beggining), ignore caching `/mantis` URLs:

```
sub vcl_recv {

    ...

    if (req.url ~ "/mantis")
    {
        return (pass);
    }

    ...
}
```

and restart varnish (usually `sudo service varnish restart` on **ubuntu**). check again and it should be fine (If its not working, clean your browser's cookies and cache).

...And, why is mantis not inside the wp-admin directory? is it a wordpress plugin?